# How to open a new Live Meeting window programmatically

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, ms-office, add-in

I am currently engaged in developing a add-in for MS outlook 2007. I need to open a new Live meeting(conferencing request) window programmatically. This is exactly same as the action performed when the new-> Live meeting button is clicked. Is there any possibility to fire the click event of the "Live Meeting" command bar button? Please help as I am new to office programming.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution for this question and learnt a lot about office programming as the project goes on. Actually we cant execute the live meeting button directly. There is no api for conferencing add in for outlook. Live meeting corresponds to the AppoinmentItem in outlook programming. So we have to use com object model to open a new AppoinmentItem and fill the body of it with appropriate details about the live meeting(actually a conference on microsoft office communications server).

We have to use the microsoft UCMA sdk to create a new confernce on OCS. Although there are many sdks available to program for ocs, ucma is the best sdk.

[Refer this to create new appoinment on outlook](http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-office-outlook-programming-vsto-c-sharp-part2)

[Study about UCMA 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd253291(office.13).aspx)